# Swift equivalent for valueForKey:

Tags: objective-c, swift, collections

This question is in regards to Swift collection types, **not** Objective-C NS collection types in Swift.

For example, how would I do this in Swift?

```
NSArray *items = // some JSON response
NSArray *names = [items valueForKey:"firstName"];
```

Note: This question is **NOT** a duplicate of the one many have marked as a duplicate of, because this question is about whether Swift has a new way of calling valueForKey: **on Swift collection types**. That question is about how to call valueForKey: in Swift **on Objective-C NS collection types**. In other words, this question addresses how to do things the new Swift way, rather than doing Swift the Objective-C way. Also, that question has no marked accepted answer.

Comment: @san It's not a duplicate because this question is about whether Swift has a new way of calling `valueForKey:` on Swift collection types. That question is about how to call `valueForKey:` in Swift on Objective-C NS collection types. In other words, this question addresses how to do things the new Swift way, rather than doing Swift the Objective-C way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `valueForKey:` in Swift, but there is a way to use `map` to achieve a similar, if not same, result.

**Similar to `valueForKey:`**

```
// items contains dictionaries
let names = items.map { $0["firstName"] as? String }

// items contains objects
let names = items.map{ $0.firstName }
```

**Similar to `valueForKeyPath:`**

```
let streets = items.map { $0["address"]?["street"] as? String }
```

**Objective-C**

For interoperability, you can also use a cast to continue using `valueForKey:` or `valueForKeyPath:`

```
let streets = (items as NSArray).valueForKeyPath("address.street") as? NSArray
```

If you are using Objective-C NS collection types like `NSDictionary` in Swift, then you can still continue to call `valueForKey:` in Swift syntax.

```
let names = items.valueForKey("firstName")
```

Comment: Doesn't Swift have it's own Dictionary type where you can use dictionary["key"]?

Comment: @Arc676 Yes, that is shorthand for `objectForKey:` which isn't the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to handle some JSON response. Take a look, at [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/lingoer/SwiftyJSON) . It's a great way to work with JSON.

You can do something like this:

let json = JSON(jsonObject)

let name = json["firstName"].stringValue